# Proving that only a specific linear transformation preserves a vector property

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

Suppose that I have a vector space $V$ spanned by the columns of a matrix $V_1$, as well as by the columns of the matrix $V_2$. Suppose also that either $V_1$ and $V_2$ have a specific structure, for instance

$$V_1=[f_1(v_1) \; f_2(v_1) \cdots f_n(v_1)] \\
V_2=[f_1(v_2) \; f_2(v_2) \cdots f_n(v_2)]$$

I have found a specific linear transformation (matrix) $T$ which has a very specific structure for which

$$V_2=V_1T$$

In other words, $T$ preserves the $f_i$ function when applied to $V_1$.
How can I show that I cannot find a linear transformation $T_2$ more general than my $T$ which still preserves the specific structure of $V_1$ when applied to it to create $V_2$? Does this transformation $T$ has a specific name?

Comment: What has this got to do with [tag:group-theory]?

Comment: $V_2=V_1T$ . Matrix times a linear map is a matrix. Do you want to write $T_{V_2}$ instead of $V_2$ and similarly for $V_1$ ?

Comment: Nono the equation I wrote is correct. Everything is to be intended as a matrix multiplication. What I meant to say is that $T$ applied to each row of $V_1$ preserves a structure, specifically if you pick the $i$th row $V_1$ you have $[f_1(v_{1i}) \; f_2(v_{1i}) \ldots f_n(v_{1i})] \to [f_1(v_{2i}) \; f_2(v_{2i}) \ldots f_n(v_{2i})]$